# CSS Hex Code Expansion

Tags: css, browser

In CSS we can either use the full 6 digit hex code for colours or we can use the 3 digit shortcuts.

How does a browser go about calculating the 6 digit hex from the 3 digit shortcut?

```
   F   F  F
  /    |  \
 /     |   \
/      |    \
FF     FF    FF
```

Simple concatenation seems a bit crude (and here's a very crude example)

```
var shortHex = "FFF";
var fullHex = shortHex[0] + shortHex[0] + [...]
```

Is the 2 digit portion derived from a calculation based on the numeric value of the single digit?

How do you get from Hex `D` with a binary value of `1101`, to `DD` with a binary value of `11011101` via calculation?

**One way** is to multiply each hex digit by 11 (hex) which gives you the result. So `D * 11` yields `DD`.

This leaves us with the question: how exactly is this done in the browser? Is it simply a case of doubling each digit or do they use another equation?

Secondly, why was this 3 digit system introduced? What inspired this decision?

Comment: Wouldn't this vary from browser to browser? It's an implementation detail after all. The spec says to simply double each digit, but it doesn't say whether an implementation should do it by concatenation, bit-flipping or multiplication.

Comment: Possibly yeah. I'd be interested in seeing the varying ways this is achieved if there's not one standard approach taken.

Answer (score 1):

Shorthand web colours take advantage of the [browser-safe web palette](http://webdesign.about.com/od/colorcharts/l/bl_colors.htm) which uses triples that are always doubled.  The shorthand colour code can only be used with values that can be doubled. Hence

```
#fff > #ffffff
#909 > #990099
```

Comment: This seems sound, re: design decision. All that's left is a source of some kind, but given that this dates back to CSS1, I'm not sure if a source can be dug up.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is you can't.

3 digit hex codes only contain less bytes compared to the 6 digit hex code. This means there is less variety of shades possible. Converting down can only happen when there is an exact match in colours. Take this example of converting colours to 3 digit values:

```
#000000 -> #000
#336699 -> #369
#123456 -> #123456
#01aa01 -> #01aa01
#a1a1a1 -> #a1a1a1
#0aa11a -> #0aa11a
```

The first two were successful as each pair of red green and blue are the same value and therefore it is shorthand for the 6 digit value. However the next few examples cannot be converted to 3 digit values as they will then become different shades. All 3 digit hex codes are predefined web safe colours and all have matching pairs.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. The question is asking how 6-digit values are derived from 3-digit values.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's simple. Each hex character corresponds to 4 bits.

> How do you get from Hex D with a binary value of 1101, to DD with a
>   binary value of 1101 1101 via calculation?

Pseudocode:

```
color4Bit := 0xD /* D in hex */
color8Bit := hex<<4 | hex /* bit shifting to the left with 4 positions, then apply either binary OR, or add the original 4 bits */
```

> Secondly, why was this 3 digit system introduced? What inspired this decision?

It's simpler. Faster to create a stylesheet. Rarely you need to be specific. 16 tones of each color are more than enough to set the general mood for a web page. Specifics are added when a professional designer deems it necessary.
For example I want a gray background. Why should I bother specifying #808080? Is it any different, fundamentally, from #888? Or if I want it to be orange? I use #F92, from memory, because this color would be close to what I imagine. So if I'm no designer, but I want to make my web functionality look beautiful, and I know CSS3, I can do all that with just 3 hex positions, gradients, shadows, etc.

Comment: well, yes. I know. I was just saying that nobody really cares at this point whether it's #808080 or #818181 or #828282, etc. Might as well be #888888 or shorter - #888. The Pseudocode I described above states this pretty clearly.